# android webview blinking once when loading data

Tags: android, webview

I have text preloaded in a webview. When the data from the internet comes, I reload the webview with the new data.

The problem is the screen blinks once during the load data transition.

Any advice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to disable the hardware accelerator on the activity:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams dfparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0, 0);
    wedview.setLayoutParams(dfparams);
    wedview.loadDataWithBaseURL(URL_SERVER, content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    wedview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
            wedview.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
    });
```

In Your layout.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wvContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
 </LinearLayout>
```