# Screen blinks once when rendering a WebView on Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-webview

I use `react-native-webview` to render a WebView in my React Native app.
All works fine on iOS, but on Android, when the WebView is rendered, my screen blinks (black, then white, then display the web page).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14346323/6111343), I tried to add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in the `<application>` tag of my `AndroidManifest.xml`, but that doesn't solve my problem. (Also, it hides all shadow effects created with `elevation` style property)

```
<DelayedComponent key={key} style={{ height: 200, ...style }}>
  <WebView
    style={{ alignSelf: "stretch" }}
    source={{ uri: /* a youtube url */ }}
    renderLoading={() => <Loading />}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    scrollEnabled={false}
  />
</DelayedComponent>
```

`<DelayedComponent>` is just a test component that renders the `<WebView>` after one second (using a basic setTimeout).

```
export class DelayedComponent extends React.PureComponent<
  { delay?: number; renderLoading?: any } & ViewProps,
  { show: boolean }
> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { show: false };
  }

  public render() {
    console.log("RENDER DELAYED", this.state);
    const loadingComp = this.props.renderLoading || (
      <Text>Just wait a second...</Text>
    );
    const { delay, renderLoading, ...forwardProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <View {...forwardProps}>
        {this.state.show ? this.props.children : loadingComp}
      </View>
    );
  }

  public async componentDidMount() {
    const delay = this.props.delay || 1000;
    await (() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay)))();
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }
}
```

The screen blinks one second after the `<DelayedComponent>` renders, when the `<WebView>` is displayed.

Here is a link to a video showing whan happens : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dX7ofANFI9oR2DFCtCRgI3_0DcsOD12B

I expect that the screen doesn't blink when the WebView is rendered, like it happens on iOS devices.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just set opacity to WebView style to 0.99.

`<WebView style={{ opacity: 0.99 }} />`

It's probably related with:
[Rendering webview on android device overlaps previous siblings from same parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872045/rendering-webview-on-android-device-overlaps-previous-siblings-from-same-parent?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Edit: Wrapping WebView component in View with `overflow: 'hidden'`: `<View style={{flex: 1, overflow: 'hidden'}}><WebView ... /></View>` also works but it can result in occasionally application crashes for some reason.

Comment: Thanks ! Blinking still occurs, but it's constrained in the `<View>` :)

Comment: I just found that this approach start causing crashes on my Pixel 1 with Android P. But found another way how fix this flickering. Just set opacity to nearly to 0.99 <WebView style={{ opacity: 0.99 }} />

Comment: I've been trying to fix this for days. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LukášPikora do you know if it's possible to apply such settings to the Android webview directly? I'm using [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) rather than react native, so I can't easily port over your suggested code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This trick worked for me, at least the user don't see the blink between those 0.5 seconds

```
<WebView
    onLoadStart={event => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ webViewHasLoadedContent: true })
      }, 500)
    }}
    style={{
      opacity: this.state.webViewHasLoadedContent ? 1 : 0,
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

i got in Flutter avoiding the resize when keyboard appear, so i add in scafold widget:

```
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

If you are using a different framework, try to avoid the resize of the keyboard.

Good luck and happy coding!